# Get value of votes from users posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-votable

I have a model `snippets` in which a user can post a snippet. The snippet that they post can be voted on using the `acts_as_votable` gem. This is working perfectly, and when a user votes, the vote count of the snippet increases by one.

Although, I am wondering is there a way to get the total value of votes for one  user's snippets they have posted?

So if a user posted 4 snippets, each with a value of 2 votes, then I am trying to get the total value of only their snippets - which is 8.

This code is used to get the votes of one individual snippet:

```
<%= @snippet.weighted_score %>
```

Although how am I able to get the total value of one users posted snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the relationship `user` `has_many` `snippets` set up? If thats the case you should be able to get all the snippets associated with the user and sum up the `votes_for`.

```
user.snippets.sum { |s| s.votes_for.size }
```

Edit: or in your case:

```
user.snippets.sum { |s| s.weighted_score }
```

References:

http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum

https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Comment: thats up to you. you could make a method in the `User` model like `def score; snippets.sum { |s| s.weighted_score }; end` and then from your view call `<%= @user.score %>` or you could directly call `<%= @user.snippets.sum { |s| s.weighted_score } %>` in the view though this isn't as clean.

Answer (score 0):

you can always see all the votes of a user by doing `@user.votes`

check out `acts_as_voter` the  the documentation [here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable), it already does whatever you want.